# Issue when download image with html2canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, html2canvas

I have a problem when using html2canvas, i need to download a div so i convert it to canvas, below is my code

```
 const handleDownload = () => {
            //custom div need to download
            let containerImage = document.createElement('div');
            containerImage.style.width = 1080
            containerImage.style.height = 1080
            for(let i = 0;i < 3;i++){
              let tmpDiv = document.createElement('div')
              tmpDiv.style.width = 1080
              tmpDiv.style.height = 300
              tmpDiv.style.background = 'red'
              containerImage.appendChild(tmpDiv)
            }
            document.body.appendChild(containerImage)
            downloadImageFromCanvas(containerImage,12,() => console.log('1'))
          }
         //download image fomr canvas
     const downloadImageFromCanvas = (Ref, id,callback) => {
              html2canvas(Ref)
                .then(async (canvas) => {
                  const photo = await getImage({ canvas, width: 1360, height: 675 });
                  const element = document.createElement('a');
                  const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(photo);
                  element.href = blobUrl;
                  element.download = `Image ${id}`;
                  element.click();
                  callback()
                })
                .catch((e) => console.log('error', e));
            };
    //convert canvas to blob
    const getImage = async ({
      canvas,
      width,
      height,
      mime = 'image/png',
      quality = 0.8,
    }) => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const tmpCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        tmpCanvas.width = width * 0.99;
        tmpCanvas.height = height;
    
        const ctx = tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(
          canvas,
          0,
          0,
          canvas.width,
          canvas.height,
          0,
          0,
          width,
          height
        );
    
        tmpCanvas.toBlob(resolve, mime, quality);
      });
    };
```

The issue is i already set the width for the div but i alway get this error

```
error DOMException: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The image argument is a canvas element with a width or height of 0
```

Does anyone have a solution for this problem? Thank you